# Play framework: call GET from server side

Tags: json, scala, playframework, response

This might be a silly question. I am beginner in Play Framework.

I have one controller which is called as below

```
GET       /getData      someController.getData()
```

And controller is implemented as below

```
Result someController() {
   SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
   obj.prop1 = "Something";
   obj.prop2 = "Something";
   return ok(Json.toJson(obj));
}
```

Now, I have another controller in which I need to call this method and get the response body say, value of obj.prop1.

I need to do to something like this

```
String s = someController().prop1;
```

In short words ***I need to get access to JSON object of response*** sent by `someController`.

I have not shown the full code, but you'll get what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

Create one private method, which handle you logic. There is no need to call controller, call the private method from controllers.

```
private SomeObject someMethod(){
 SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
 obj.prop1 = "Something";
 obj.prop2 = "Something";
 return obj
}

Result someController1(){
 SomeObject obj = someMethod();
}

Result someController2(){
 SomeObject obj = someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't do that. Additionally it adds code duplication to my site.

Comment: I'm essentially writing same code at two location. One at controller and one in your method

Comment: i think there is only write response code, because the private method return the object, like in above example.

Comment: The code clarity is more also important as like code duplication.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara is right - this is valid approach, GaneshS you don't need to use the logic inside first action (which you're calling "Controller") as you can use someMethod() in both